# Theme customization is not loaded with MenuInflater

Tags: android, android-theme

I've noticed an unexpected behavior with my Theme customization and the inflater.

I have the following theme with the customization on the `SearchView`

```
<style name="GTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchView</item>
    <!--...-->
</style>

<style name="SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <item name="iconifiedByDefault">false</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

And for the configuration of the search

`xml/searchable.xml`

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"/>
```

`menu/options_menu.xml`

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_view_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

When I the `SearchView` is created from the method `onCreateOptionsMenu` the customization is not loaded

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    //Here I can already see that the costumization is missing with the debugger
    //...
    return true
}
```

However if I create a Layout with the `SearchView` a for a fragment for example :

```
layout/fragment_explorer.xml

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.geocodle.android.ui.explorer.ExplorerFragment">
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="true">

    </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

</FrameLayout>
```

In the Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explorer, container, false);
}
```

Then  my `SearchView` has the customization

In the first case the Layout is inflated by the MenuInflater and in the second case by the LayoutInflater. 
I read that in the case the context is not Theme aware like with ApplicationContext the customization is not loaded. But in my case both use the Activity as context.

Do you know if there is a reason why with the menu Inflater the customization is missing ?

**Update**

Actually the context is not from the same instance in both cases as I thought. Even if the `MenuInflater` is retrieved from the Activity with `this.getMenuInflater()`, the context in `SearchView` (provided by the MenuInflater) is an instance of `ContextThemeWrapper` wherea with the `LayoutInflater` the context is my activity `GeoCodleActivity`. So it seems it's the reason why the behavior is not the same. So now the question is how to get the Activity as context in the MenuInflater. I tried new  `MenuInflater (this)` as suggested by @pskink (thanks for your advices). This time I have the correct theme but then when I retrieve the SearchView it's null. The break point I added in the SearchView constructor is not even triggered

```
    MenuInflater menuInflater = new MenuInflater(this);
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    //With this the SearchView is not null but Theme is not customized
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);


    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    //SearchAction has not Searchview
    MenuItem searchAction =  menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    //searchView is null
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchAction.getActionView();
```

Comment: I already did this and this confirmed what I explain here. The context return the default Searchview theme attributes values with MenuInflater. For example If I add a custom layout in my style, in   a.getResourceId(R.styleable.SearchView_layout, R.layout.abc_search_view)  the two parameters reference R.layout.abc_search_view (the default)

Comment: In both cases `defStyleAttr ` is the same value : 2130968901. it's the reference of `R.attr.searchViewStyle`; However the `TintTypedArray` returned by `TintTypedArray.obtainStyledAttributes(context, attrs, R.styleable.SearchView, defStyleAttr, 0)` does not  contains the same values.  For example at the indexes   a[ 24..31] there is [3, 396, 4, 2131230951, 0, 0, 3, 166] with LayoutInflater and  [3, 261, 4, 2131230756, 0, 0, 3, 166,] with MenuInflater.

Comment: However still debugging I just noticed that actually the context is not from the same instance as I thought. Event if the `MenuInflater` is retrieved from the Activity with this.getMenuInflater(), the context in SearchView (provided by the MenuInflater) is an instance of  `ContextThemeWrapper` wherea with the `LayoutInflater` the context is my activity `GeoCodleActivity`. So it seems it's the reason why the  behavior is not the same. So now the question is how to get the Activity  as context in the MenuInflater

Comment: tried `new MenuInflater(...)` instead of `getMenuInflater()`? [Activity#getMenuInflater()](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#4225) is strange... (or maybe its ok as they dont want developers to make any styled customization in the action bar...)

Comment: It seems to work. I need to do some checks then I will update the case. Great Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually with `new MenuInflater(this)` (this is my Activity), After inflating, the searchView I Retrieve with `searchAction.getActionView()` is null. It's not if I use `getMenuInflater()`.

Comment: so setup a breakpoint in MenuInflater#newInstance method and see what happens

Comment: The constructor just set variables. The job is done in `MenuInflater.inflate()`. It will be tricky to debug the parser. I will try then update. I should also try to understand why getMenuInflater doesn't do work. But I really start thinking that implementing the menu in the Layout is a better solution for customization.

Comment: did you check the returned value from newInstace method? is it null? did you debug that method?

Comment: It's not. ‘menuInflater.inflate()‘ doesn't fail. But the SearchAction inflated in the menu doesn't contain the SearchView as expected following thé configuration.

Comment: I asked what value is returned from **MenuInflater#newInstance** method, not `MenuInflater#inflate`

Comment: MenuInflater#newInstance is not call (I added a break point). Not sure to understand what you want I check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SupportMenuInflater` instead of `MenuInflater` it works as expected. Of course My activivity extend `AppCompatActivity`

So in `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
MenuInflater menuInflater = new SupportMenuInflater(this);
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom **ThemedSearchView**

```
class ThemedSearchView @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
, defTheme: Int = R.style.CustomSearchView
) : SearchView(ContextThemeWrapper(context, defTheme), attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

And you can apply your own theme then only to **SearchView**